# Normal map rendering is broken , in Renderer2D using Light2D and shader graph with normal map

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

there,
Because normal map rendering is broken. I very comfused.

Using Light2D in Renderer2D, And Sprite Lit shader graph with Normal map.
Graph is very simple. Here is this graph.

[image]

However this shader is not rendered correct.

When camera is opposite and no angle, rendering is very good.
But camera is rotated, Light hit area moved incurrectoly.
Here is recording this matter gif.

[image]

Upon investigation, it appears that the position of the UV itself is distorted to begin with.

[image]

If shader is Unlit. Rendering is currect.
But I want to normal map effect.

How can I fix it?
Or How can I construct scene avoiding this matter, and using Light 2D and normal map.

---

my environments
Unity 2022.3.4f1
Universal RP 14.0.8
Shader Graph 14.0.8

*This is png I using in test.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I transfered my project Renderer2D to 3DRendering pipelines.
It is not supported in renderer2D camera rotate x or y axis, as far as my investigatin.